# PHP Abbreviated month name

Tags: php

I am trying to use dates with abbreviated months in php. I've already tried `d ([.\t-])* m Y` found on their documentation but what I am getting is this `20 ([.    -])* 01 2016`

How can I use abbreviated months like `10 Jan 2016` in PHP?

Comment: Please share more details, like the **exact** code you are using to trigger the problem - is that a regular expression around the `\t` or what should that be used for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Today's answer was brought to you by the letter M (capital) and a link to the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: always use php date format. m-y-d mm-dd-yy will produce a completely different result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's I found it, even thought it's really late but maybe someone needs it
basic

```
date('M',strtotime($dateValue))
```

https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/date.php

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `substring` function:

```
substr($month,0,3);
```

Comment: Please share more details - where does `$month` come from?